# Updating Microsoft Access using OleDbAdapter.Update

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, oledb, ms-access-2010

I have been able to bind the data in my MS Access database to textboxes on a form.  But when I update the data, no changes are made to the database.  I made a simplified example to demonstrate my problem.  The form contains only two textboxes (txtFirstName and txtLastName) and two buttons (Save and Refresh).  Refresh just reloads the DataTable from the database.  I load the record with ID 1 and try to update.  The code is below.  I know that the updates to the textboxes also update the DataTable.  However, the Update function of the data adapter does nothing because no Update commands are generated by the OleDbCommandBuilder.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks so much!

---

```
    // Global data
    public DataTable CaseTable = new DataTable();
    private OleDbCommand dbCmd;
    private OleDbDataAdapter adapter;
    private OleDbCommandBuilder builder;
    private OleDbConnection dbConn = null;

    public frmCustomer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CaseTable.Columns.Add("ID");
        CaseTable.Columns.Add("FirstName");
        CaseTable.Columns.Add("LastName");
        this.txtFirstName.DataBindings.Add("Text", CaseTable, "FirstName"); //, true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        this.txtLastName.DataBindings.Add("Text", CaseTable, "LastName"); //, true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    }

    private void frmCustomer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dbConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Customers.accdb");
        dbCmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * From Customers Where ID = 1", dbConn);
        adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(dbCmd);
        builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
        RefreshForm();
    }

    private void RefreshForm()
    {
        CaseTable.Clear();
        adapter.Fill(CaseTable);

        if (CaseTable.Rows.Count < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Item Not Found", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (adapter.Update(CaseTable) < 1)
            MessageBox.Show("No updates");
    }

    private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshForm();
    }
```

Comment: Try using GetChanges() on your DataTable. For example something like
DataTable dt = CaseTable.GetChanges()
adapter.Update(dt)

Comment: I had tried something similar but, for some reason, CaseTable.GetChanges() is null.  I know that the table has been updated, so I can't understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this works, but here is how I fixed my problem.  At the end of RefreshForm I add the line
   CaseTable.Rows[0].BeginEdit();
and at the beginning of the Save event handler I add the line
   CaseTable.Rows[0].EndEdit();

Now the changes are carried back to the database.  I'm not sure why none of the online references I found made reference to this.